# PHP api to upload and save images on server without form using Python script

Tags: php, python-3.x, api

I am trying to build a simple php api which shall run on a remote server and save images (which are being sent to the api from a Python script) to a particular directory on the server.

I came across this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23232766/image-upload-receive-api) and changed it for my use case but it doesn't seem to be working. What am I missing here? I want to move the file to `/var/sftp/uploads`. Where should I place this php file and how should I access it? Which os user should own this file on Ubuntu linux and should it have write permissions to `/var/sftp/uploads`?

```
<?php
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);

if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png"))
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts)) {

  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {

    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";

  } else {

    //Move the file to the uploads folder
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/sftp/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

  }
} else {
  //File type was invalid, so throw up a red flag!
  echo "Invalid File Type";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code and it worked. I also ensured that the `/var/sftp/uploads` folder was owned by `www-data` so that it could write the files there.

```
<?php
$target_dir = "/var/sftp/uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
  $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);
  if($check !== false) {
    echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
    $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
    echo "File is not an image.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
  }
}

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
  echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["size"] > 500000) {
  echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
  echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
  $uploadOk = 0;
}

// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
  echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances , the httpd will not be able to access folder like "/var/sftp/uploads/".

Hence, please create a sub-folder known as "uploadfile" (this subfolder should be right under the folder of your php file) and make it write permitted.

After that please change the line

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "/var/sftp/uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

to

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "./uploadfile/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
```

After you have performed a file upload, please check whether the file can be seen inside this "uploadfile" folder

Comment: Hi Ken. I tried your code but the file is not getting transferred. I am using the Python requests library to transfer the file. Following is my code: import requests
file_name=input("Enter the image file name to transfer: ")
with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
    r = requests.post('https://example.com/file_upload.php', files={file_name: f})
    print("Response:",r)

Comment: instead of python transfer, can you use php file transfer ?

Comment: I am developing a Python desktop app. So I would like to use Python. Within the Python code, I am calling the PHP end-point for file transfer. I have an update: The php api is working fine now but in case of a missing file, it returns a web server error. If I restart the server and then try again, the file transfer works fine. Is it happening because of some php cache?